# Publish Test Coverage Report on AzureDevops failure

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have some tests that run, and produces a report.xml. The task : `publish task results` shows the visual representation of the tasks that failed, passed etc.
However, I want to have code coverage result as well. But I get the following warning and I do not see any code coverage info. I also see that the artifact is produced, But no coverage information. [image: Warning]

[image: Code]

my concerns: (1) Does a separate file with coverage information already be present in the repository post testing?

(2) The task `PublishCodeCoverageResults@1` does not produce a coverage from the testreport.xml? Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 1):

PublishCodeCoverageResults task is used to publish Cobertura or JaCoCo code coverage results from a build. It will not produce a coverage, it will publish the existing files to the build-artifact page.
SummaryFileLocation is used to specify the path of the summary file containing code coverage statistics. So in your issue, the file should be in there '$(system.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/build/test/report.xml' before the pipeline starts. (you could regard it as something like a template summary with JaCoCo format, after the build run, the result should update the file and publish it in the artifact)

Then you will get something as this:
[image]

[image]

For your reference, if you already have report file(code coverage HTML report) generate from previous build tasks, you could directly use reportDirectory in the task.
Here is the [official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/publish-code-coverage-results-v1?view=azure-pipelines) for more details.